# Best way to implement this record (store date along with ID and quantity)?

Tags: java, android

Im wondering the best way of storing the following information:

I have an Account Object, within each account object I need to keep track of date, items purchased on that date, and the number of items . This is in addition to many other things such as client ID for the account. Im about to implement this in the following way

```
class Account{

int clientID;

LinkedHashMap<String(the date), Map<int(itemID), int(quantity)>> = new ...

...


}
```

I was wondering if anyone has any time before I go ahead and implement this? I mean other thing I thought of was an inner class such as

```
Class Account{

class Item{

String Date

Array<Int> itemID

Array<Int> item quantity

}
```

But I feel the first way wold be better. THanks for your suggestions.

P.S I know there's issues in the code like the brackets in the hashmap this is just to help you see what I'm getting at :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be good design:

```
public class Acount {
    private int clientId;
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
}

public class Purchase {
    private Date date;
    private Map<Item, Integer> itemsCount;
}

public class Item {
    private int itemId;
}
```

1. An `Account` has a `clientId` and a list of purchases.
2. Each `Purchase` has a date and a map that identifies the purchased `Item`s and the quantity of each one.

Comment: I think he wants the qty of each item, not the total of the purchase, so you should change the Purchase class to be a Map from Item to Qty, rather than 2 separate fields, otherwise you could just do list.size() and not need the itemCount.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to store id and data

```
HashMap<String, String> multiMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

// Put elements to the hashMap
hashMap.put("id1", "data1");
hashMap.put("id2", "data2");  hashMap.put("id3", "data3");
```